# Maximum Requests Parse server can handle

Tags: parse-server

How many requests Parse server can handle? I read somewhere it is 10,000 but someone wrote 14,000 on other place. Can anyone tell what is the exact number of requests it can handle?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, this is question does not fit this site. Please proceed to the [help center](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help) and have a look at what is on and off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a free plan, Parse limits 30 requests/second ~ 1800 requests/min.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarvis If I helped you why not press the tick next to my answer please

Comment: Is there a way to increase the number of requests?

Comment: @jarvis I think you can if you have a paid plan (also you unticked my post by the way, not sure if that was on purpose or not)